# How does Cygwin's setup-x86.exe look for the Cygwin installation?

Tags: cygwin

I just installed Cygwin by running setup-x86.exe and now have a directory for Cygwin itself

`C:/cygwin`

and a directory for its packages

`C:/cygwin-packages`.

Now, when I run setup-x86.exe again to add additional packages, it wants to install Cygwin again. According to the documentation this happens if setup-x86.exe can't find the existing Cygwin installation. I tried running setup-x86.exe from inside C:\cygwin but that didn't work either.

1. How does setup decide where to look for the installation?
2. How can I get it to find my installation?

Comment: What do you mean by "a directory for its packages"? I have a directory (I use `C:\tools\cygwin`) that contains the packages downloaded by `setup-x86.exe`, in a subdirectory whose name is based on which mirror I choose (mine is `http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.kernel.org%2fsourceware%2fcygwin%2f`). Cygwin itself, including all installed packages, is under `C:\cygwin`. If `C:\cygwin-packages` is for the *downloaded* package files, that's fine. If you're trying to put *installed* packages in a separate directory, that's not supported (and I don't think you can even tell the setup program to do that).

Answer (score 0):

setup looks in the registry, in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Cygwin\setup\rootdir, for its installation directory.

The setup you described, in which the Cygwin core is in one directory and installed packages are in another, isn't supported.  Everything is supposed to go together in one directory.  I'm sure that at this point you've confused Cygwin about where it's supposed to be installed.

If you're worried about intermixing Cygwin core and packages, don't.  That's how it's supposed to work.  setup will keep track of the installed package files and remove them if you uninstall something.

At this point I think your best course is to remove the `C:/cygwin-packages` directory, reset the registry key above to `C:/cygwin`, then reinstall all of your packages.

Comment: On my system, `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\cygwin\setup\rootdir` is not set, which probably tells Cygwin to use the default, `C:\cygwin`.

Comment: It depends on what the OP means by "a directory for its packages"; see my comment on the question.

Comment: @Keith Thompson it is always set unless you used the new flag **--no-write-registry**.if you install a 32bit version on a 64bit OS it writes to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Cygwin\setup\rootdir**
also it can be in **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Cygwin\setup\rootdir** if you installed without admin or with the install for just me option
so check 4 places
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\cygwin\setup\rootdir
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\cygwin\setup\rootdir
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Wow6432Node\software\cygwin\setup\rootdir
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Wow6432Node\software\cygwin\setup\rootdir